# Map marker gets covered by surrounding data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-embed

I'm using Google Maps Embed API and the markers within the iframe get partly covered by surrounding place labels. How could I increase their z-index or whatever property necessary so they have priority over anything else in the map?

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=MY_API_KEY&q=Tarragona">
</iframe>
```

Output looks like this:

[image]

I opened a bug report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/260348804

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll find out that there is no z-index or any other property for that purpose. It looks like a bug though. I could not find an existing bug in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:188814&s=created_time:desc). You might want to open one and to provide a working demo. Also, you can link to your question in the bug report, and add the report link to your question once it's open.

Comment: @bdcoder z-index is only available for [Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript). The question is about [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started). So what MrUpsidown said above about not having z-index on the documentation is true. And OP should follow his advise on filing a bug on the Issue Tracker.

Comment: @Yrll - Sorry - your absolutely correct - I mistakenly assumed the Javascript API when in fact the OP did say the Embed API.

Comment: I looked through your bug report and saw that it was marked as "Won't Fix".  Since they marked it as so because it is working as intended,  you should try filing a [Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188814&template=788210) instead for the Maps Embed to have a z-index feature. But looking at your bug report, I think it would be nice also for you to try what you want in Maps Javascript instead in Maps embed, because Maps Embed have significant limitations compared to Maps Javascript.

Comment: @Yrll I'm afraid that the customer doesn't want to pay for the Javascript API. I still do not understand why when looking for some cities I sometimes get a random marker and other times I get the city highlited. I don't think that it is an intended behaviour.

Comment: @Yrll TBH, Google's answer to this bug report is kind of unacceptable. The "solution" provided is not at all a solution, merely a workaround. I have commented on the bug report and asked them to reconsider. Sometimes you have to insist.

Comment: I took a look at your comment and I agree. I voted on it also hoping that they would reopen the bug. Thanks for the insight @MrUpsidown!

Comment: They just reopened it. Wait and see...